# How to send field name for required true validation in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

Here is what my form field,

```
$this->addElement( 'text', 'title', array(
            'placeholder' => 'Title',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters'    => array( 'StringTrim' ),
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
        ) );
```

I Simply need the error string like: 
Title is required and can't be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$this->addElement( 'text', 'title', array(
        'placeholder' => 'Title',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array( 'StringTrim' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'validators' => array(
                array('NotEmpty', false, array('messages' => array(Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Title is required and cant be empty')))
        )
    ) );
```